# PySpark: Filter out all lines, which have more columns than header line

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

```
df = spark.read.csv('input.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

Let's say that 'input.csv' file contains following data:

```
id, name, age
1, John, 20
2, Mike, 33
3, Phil, 19, 180, 78
4, Sean, 40
```

I would like to filter out rows, which contain more columns than the header and save it to different output somewhat like this (illustratively):

```
df2 = df.filter(condition1) #condition1 = rows which have more columns than header
df = df.filter(condition2) #condition2 = rows which have same amount or less columns than header
df.show()
df2.show()
```

So I would get output as follows:

```
+---+------+----+
| id|  name| age|
+---+------+----+
|  1|  John|  20|
|  2|  Mike|  33|
|  4|  Sean|  40|
+---+------+----+


+---+------+----+
| id|  name| age|
+---+------+----+
|  3|  Phil|  19|
+---+------+----+
```

So far I've found nothing. Currently it just shrinks the row to fit the header with no way of obtaining it. What can I do?
Thanks

EDIT:
The schema does not necessarily need to be "id", "name, "age". It should literally take anything, so the filtering can not be dependent on a specific column. Moreover, the solution can not be exclusive to a specific type of reading, the data will be received based on what a user chooses and only thing that can be modified are parameters and options.

Answer (score 2):

You can read as a text file and find the number of columns in each row. Obtain a df with the id's of the rows having more than 3 columns. Then do a `semi` or `anti` join to the dataframe (obtained with `read.csv`) using the `id`.

```
text = spark.read.text('input.csv')
textdf = text.selectExpr(
    "value",
    "size(split(value, ',')) len",
    "split(value, ',')[0] id"
).filter('len > 3')

textdf.show()
+----------------+---+---+
|           value|len| id|
+----------------+---+---+
|3,Phil,19,180,78|  5|  3|
+----------------+---+---+


df = spark.read.csv('input.csv', header=True)

df1 = df.join(textdf, 'id', 'anti')
df2 = df.join(textdf, 'id', 'semi')

df1.show()
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1|John| 20|
|  2|Mike| 33|
|  4|Sean| 40|
+---+----+---+

df2.show()
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  3|Phil| 19|
+---+----+---+
```

Comment: This solution will drop the extra columns in the rows that include more than 3 items.

Comment: @AmirMaleki yes, but it agrees with the expected output of the OP.

Comment: you're right that's what he's looking for.

Comment: The problem is, that it needs to work for all kinds of input files with various structure. There does not need to be an id or any unique column. How can I obtain the row without the id?